# Adding space in app name for iOS 11

Tags: xcode, ios11

I am facing very abnormal issue as in iOS 11, space is getting removed between app name in iOS 11.

I have tried to get space in between app name using following steps:

1. Open info.plist as Source code(right click, open as...)
2. Find CFBundleDisplayName
3. Replace normal space with unicode `&#x2007;`

But `&#x2007;` is displayed as a double space in the Settings app on iOS 11 and the Home screen on iOS 9 & 10.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just open `info.plist` and set the `Bundle Name` with space.

[image]

Screenshot from iPhone Simulator 11.2

[image]

Comment: In iOS 11, if bundle name's characters length is greater than 12 then it will remove spaces between the name.
Ex: "AAA BBBBB CCCCCCC-DDDDDDDD" will become "AAABBBBBCC..."

Answer (score 5):

If anyone is using an .xcconfig file for configuring the app, simply copy and paste the FIGURE SPACE character.

So instead of

```
PRODUCT_NAME = App Name
```

use

```
PRODUCT_NAME = App Name
```

Looks the same, but the space on the second snippet is actually &#x2007 .
I used WebStorm to copy and paste the character, and not XCode.

Comment: you have explained so well but, your string gives 2 character spaces. I've modified the answer and added my solution below.

Answer (score 0):

I changed the name with space in `Info.plist` -> `Bundle Display Name` -> `Hello World`. This worked for me...